# Not sure about Singleton

Tags: java, singleton

If I have a singleton class like:

```
public class MySingleton(){
    private static MySingleton istance;
    private int element;

    private MySingleton(){element = 10;}     

    public static MySingleton getIstance() {
        if(istance == null)
            istance = new Mysingleton();
        return istance;
    }
    public void setElement(int i ){
        element = i;
    }
    public int getElement(){
        return element;
    }
}
```

and I want to change element's value by calling

```
MySingleton.getIstance().setElement(20)
```

Will it change the element value for the istance? Here's an example:

```
... main () {
    MySingleton.getIstance().setElement(20);
    System.out.prinln(MySingleton.getIstance().getElement());
    // It displays 10, why ?
```

Comment: You need to make your get method `synchronized`.  Also, your `getIstance()` method has no return type.  How is this even compiling?  Lastly, when I run your code (corrected to make it compile), I get `20`, as expected.

Comment: public static getIstance() is wrong it should be  public static MySingleton getIstance()

Comment: The code shown gives the expected result. Probably you're looking at the execution of an old compilation unit of your class.

Comment: Would you please correct all your typo ? (Mysingleton, prinln)

Comment: Are you sure it displays 10? It display 20 - I am very sure!

Comment: @azurefrog `synchronized` has nothing to do in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use an `enum` as it is simpler and thread safe (but not your getter/setter)

```
public enum MySingleton() {
    INSTANCE;

    private int element = 10;

    public void setElement(int element) { this.element = element; }
    public int getElement() { return element; }
}

MySingleton.INSTANCE.setElement(20);
System.out.prinln(MySingleton.INSTANCE.getElement()); // prints 20.
```

Comment: Or a *Static Inner Class* :)

Comment: @TheLostMind it's a more complicated way to achieve much the same thing ;)

Comment: My love for *static initializers* takes me there.. Ya, you are right. The Enum  approach has relatively less overhead  :)

Comment: @TheLostMind `enum` has a static initializer too. As does `interface`s ;)

Comment: @HaZe As do I as I have only 15 years exp in Java, I learn by answering these questions ;)

Comment: @TheLostMind This shows the variable `A.a` is initialised in the static initializer for the interface. https://gist.github.com/peter-lawrey/ebe30191c32c5dd3cfc8

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Wow.. That was fast.. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @TheLostMind do you like the title, as it is a program without a class file. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Yep.. loved it.. Actually it made me laugh.. There's always something new to learn from you.. Thanks again.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your code block above was copied in or just retyped, but there were a few basic compilation issues I saw with it - when you're setting MySingleton in getInstance, you need to check capitalization. Also, your class declaration shouldn't have (parentheses). After fixing these two things and running basic main, I got 20.

This is the same as what you had - no synchronization or anything else, but on a single thread it doesn't seem necessary.

```
public class MySingleton{
    private static MySingleton istance;
    private int element;

    private MySingleton(){element = 10;}     

    public static MySingleton getIstance() {
        if(istance == null)
            istance = new MySingleton();
        return istance;
    }
    public void setElement(int i ){
        element = i;
    }
    public int getElement(){
        return element;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MySingleton.getIstance().getElement());
        MySingleton.getIstance().setElement(20);
        System.out.println(MySingleton.getIstance().getElement());
    }

}
```

should have an output of

```
10
20
```

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure if your code really work, how azurefrog say, make your code synchronized, and in youre line `public static getIstance() {` you need to set the return type.

Comment: `synchronized` has nothing to do in this case. This isn't a multi threaded environment, OP is using the main thread only.

Comment: Why use a singleton on just a main thread? He maybe use only the "one thread" just to simplify the example for the question, the best is to add synchronized in his singleton

Comment: That's something we don't know. And if this is the specific case, it should be proven by the code OP posts. Otherwise, the problem cannot be reproduced and the question should be flagged/closed for that reason.